# How to get the most repeated substring between two strings?

Tags: php

For example, I've two strings:

```
$str1 = "one two three";

$str2 = "one two two three three three";
```

How can I get **three** as the final result in above case?

Comment: `explode(" ",$str1)`,`explode(" ",$str2)` and then use array manipulation functions

Comment: Will all strings be words separated by spaces or can it contain anything?

Comment: By using explodes, the strings will be separated.

Comment: Have you got expected solution?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$str1 = "one two three";

$str2 = "one two two three three three";

$array1=explode(" ",$str1);
$array2=explode(" ",$str2);
$result=array_merge($array1,$array2);
$count=array_count_values($result);
arsort($count);
echo key($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code:

```
$arr = array_count_values(explode(" ", $yourstr));
asort($arr);

reset($array);

//get first val
echo current($array), PHP_EOL ;

//get first key
echo key($array), PHP_EOL ;
```

for more info see: [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode, and put the values in array. Then fetch what values you want based in the index of the array you have created.

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = "one two two three three three";
print_r( array_count_values(str_word_count($words, 1)) );
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
)
```

Check Manual for **[str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)** and **[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)**